# How can I insert a date into a textbox using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

I'd like to put today's date into a textbox using javascript; Here is my code:

```
function add_event() {
    var currentDate = new Date()
    var day = currentDate.getDate()
    var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
    var year = currentDate.getFullYear()
    var day1 = day + "." + month + "." + year

    var html = '<tr><td class="date"><input type="text" name="date_evnt"  value="?"></td> <td class="title"><input type="text" value="New Event"></td> <td class="delete"><input type="button" value="-"></td></tr>';
    $('#events-table').append(html);

    events_table_events();
}
```

I'm not sure how to set the date into textbox name `date_evnt`.

Comment: Which date do you want to go into the input? Also, may I suggest creating `tr`,`td`, and `input` nodes rather than raw HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to put the `day1` value in `date_evnt` you can do this:

```
var html = '<tr><td class="date"><input type="text" name="date_evnt"  value="' + day1 + '"></td> <td class="title"><input type="text" value="New Event"></td> <td class="delete"><input type="button" value="-"></td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
function add_event() {
    var currentDate = new Date(), day = currentDate.getDate(),
        month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1, year = currentDate.getFullYear(),
        day1 = day + "." + month + "." + year;

    var txt1 = $('<input/>', { 'name':'date_evnt', 'value':day1 }),
        tr = $("<tr/>"), td = $('<td/>');

    tr.append(td.attr('class','title').html('New Event '))
    .append(td.append(txt1))
    .append(td.append($('<button/>', {'html':'-'})));

    $('#events-table').append(tr);
}
add_event();
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/jvJZZ/1/)